# Getting inaccurate data from GA4 compared to regular Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I've made a python script to get the number of active users on my site, but I've recently found out that the number I get from GA4 is less than that of the regular GA.

For the information, I am getting the number of active users in the last 5 minutes, which I assume is the correct number regarding GA when it counts active users.

If I get the default duration, which is 30 minutes, then I get even more data.

As an example, in GA I have "310" active users at the moment, but on GA4, I have "83" in the last 5 minutes, and "448" in the last 30 minutes.

Here is my code:

```
#Runs a realtime report on a Google Analytics 4 property.
client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
#Run the request.
request = RunRealtimeReportRequest(
    property=f"properties/{property_id}",
    metrics=[Metric(name="activeUsers")],
        minute_ranges=[MinuteRange(start_minutes_ago=29, end_minutes_ago=0)]
)
#Parse the response.
response = client.run_realtime_report(request)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two versions do not measure the same thing, with GA4 expected to show more users:

> The Realtime report in Google Analytics 4 properties counts users who
> engaged with your app/site for any non-zero amount of time during the
> previous 30 minutes, while the Streamview (realtime) report in
> Universal Analytics Standard/360 properties counts any user who
> triggered an event during the previous five minutes.

[Source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9408920?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you. This explains it.